# MongoDB authorization issues

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I just learned to use mongoDB, and after deploying it on the server, I created a user. When I use mongoose to connect, I can connect without even entering the account password!

```
connectionStr:`mongodb://xxxx:27017/test`
```

But when I use MongoDB Compass to connect, if I don't enter the account password, I can't connect. I want to know why this is the case. Because I have turned on Security, I think it is impossible to connect using mongoose without entering the password.

[image]

Comment: Now I found that Compass can login without password...

Comment: Please don't past images, use formatted text for code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can always connect to MongoDB without password.

However, without authentication you cannot execute any command (apart from `db.getMongo()`):

```
C:\>mongo localhost
MongoDB shell version v4.4.0
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/localhost?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("f44422c7-f462-405a-8432-594d75ff451a") }
MongoDB server version: 4.4.0
ANONYMOUS@localhost> db.getMongo()
connection to 127.0.0.1:27017
ANONYMOUS@localhost> db.stats()
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "command dbStats requires authentication",
        "code" : 13,
        "codeName" : "Unauthorized"
}
ANONYMOUS@localhost> exit
bye
```

There is another special point in MongoDB. When you enable security and start the service then you can still connect to database without username/password - **unless** you created an initial admin user.

This function is called [Localhost Exception](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-users/#localhost-exception)

Another note, when you connect to Mongo then you should specify the authentication database, see [Authentication failure while trying to save to mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470)